# User manual template for OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

Where should I look for a user manual template for OpenOffice 3.2 Writer?  I am busy wading through Google results, but I ask here in case somebody knows of a definite good source and has possible used such a template from there.

Comment: Have you tried http://templates.services.openoffice.org/en/

Comment: I have thanks.  I'm currently looking at a decent handful of templates from there.